# Paypal PHP Rest API SDK - Things don’t appear to be working right now

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am currently trying to test my implementation of the paypal rest api sdk. However when i login via the sandbox account it takes forever to load and then i get "Things don’t appear to be working right now."

Before i narrow it down to an issue on paypals side i just want to make sure i have my code setup right. I read that errors in the code can cause this.

```
<?php 
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
    '***',
    '***'
    )
);

if (isset($_GET['created'], $_GET['paymentId'], $_GET['PayerID'])){
    $paymentId = $_GET['paymentId'];
    $payerId = $_GET['PayerID'];

    $payment = Payment::get($paymentId, $paypal);

    $execute = new PaymentExecution();
    $execute->setPayerId($payerId);

    try{
        $result = $payment->execute($execute, $paypal);
        //Success
        header("Location: createInstance.php?created");
    }catch(Exception $e){
        $data = json_decode($e-getData());
        header("Location: createInstance.php?error&message=".$data->message);
        die();
    }

}else{
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

    $item = new Item();
    $item->setName('Test Item')
        ->setCurrency('AUD')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice('9.99');

    $itemList = new ItemList();
    $itemList->setItems([$item]);

    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('AUD')
        ->setTotal('9.99');

    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($itemList)
        ->setDescription('Test Description')
        ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

    $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('******') <--Full Url
        ->setCancelUrl('******'); <--Full URL

    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
        ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

    try{
        $payment->create($paypal);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        die($e);
    }

    $approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
    header("Location: {$approvalUrl}");
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question but just as a note, I've often encountered problems working with PayPal's API in the sandbox, from accounts not being created to the service seemingly not working to any number of problems that turned out to be their servers. I'm not saying it's exactly what it is here but PayPal don't seem overly enthusiastic about spending much on their sandbox environments.

Comment: Looks like i am about to throw it out and stick with stripe

Comment: BrainTree is very good, and PayPal is fairly good, but the sandboxing difficulties make it tiresome. Generally I’ve waited over 24 hours before hearing back from support too. Maybe set it down for the night and try again tomorrow, usually the problems are temporary. Assuming it isn’t your code of course!